# Export multiple tables to one text file in Access

Tags: ms-access-2007, text-files

As the title goes, I've several tables in one Access 2007 database and I need to export them to a text file. So far, DoCmd.TransferText has helped me perform one-on-one export. But now I need to retrieve certain fields from different tables and combine them into one text file. Hopefully this will clarify:

> write into file.txt
>
> table1.field1
>
> table2.field1, table2.field2 ... table2.fieldN
>
> table3.field1

Restrictions: I can't use a query to combine the tables, because they are totally dissimilar. I cannot use system commands, eg.: COPY, etc.

Bonus: I'm also looking for a solution that creates a completely flat text file, removing CR&LF from each record. Something like:

> table1.field1&table2.field1&table2.field2 ... tableN.fieldN

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION in a single query to sequentially output the tables, padding the selects for tables that have fewer columns than others.  UNION is like append, but for SQL resultsets.